# How to get the access to my custom Javascript's class type object in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a class like this:

```js
class Cat { 
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  meow() {
    console.log('meow');
  }
}
```

I have a JS script in an `iframe` where I try to check my object to see if it is an instance of the `Cat` class

```js
if (somevar isinstanceof Cat){
  cat.meow();
}
```

It results in an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cat is not defined.

I was trying to check it like `window.parent.Cat` but it seems not to be in the `window` at all, only objects declared with `var` can be accessed by window. How can I get my `Cat` class in the iframe?

Comment: Include the JS file which defines the `Cat` object in the page which is loaded in the iframe. This also avoids any potential security issues with reading a parent page from a iframe.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok but i need that JS file in my main window as well

Comment: That's not a problem. The two locations are completely separate documents.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i've just tested that and in my case it is a problem because my `somevar` is instance of the `Cat` class that is located in the parent window. And checking it for `Cat` class that is in iframe returns `false`.

Comment: It sounds like the code is working, but not giving the result you expect. I'd debug exactly what `somevar` *is*

Comment: The thing is that when i include JS file to iframe i have two different classes named `Cat`. One is in the main window and second is in iframe. And my `somevar` - which is an instance of main window class `Cat` cannot be an instance of iframe's `Cat` class. I got my `somevar` variable like `somevar = window.parent.cat_ins`